# How to chop/chunk videos using any AWS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, aws-fargate

I want to chop a huge number of videos (~50k) into 1 min segments each.

Eg - A video with 60 min duration will be chopped into 60 mp4 files i.e 1m/video

I looked into media convert service but it's has not the option to do.

What is the scalable solution do it?

P.S currently I am using EC2 , ffmpeg to do this job, its very slow.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Elemental MediaConvert is a file-based video transcoding service and does not support  chopping video content like other tools do such as [Adobe Premire Pro](https://www.adobe.com/ca/products/premiere.html). If you are looking at chopping video, use other tools then you can use AWS to perform supported operations like transcoding video using MediaConvert.

Answer (score 0):

AWS MediaConvert will create [HLS (HTTP Live Streaming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) output.  HLS is kinda like what you are asking, its a video chopped into small chunks.  Usually it's broken out into different versions of the video so the client can choose which stream to play based on size and quality.

There are serval online guides on how to do this using AWS MediaConvert.   [Here is one.](https://stackpill.com/story/3/convert-mp4-to-hls-or-dash-using-aws-elemental-mediaconvert/)

You can also automate this using aws lambda. Where you can also define the size of the video chunks you want created.  Then store them in S3.